# How does error page shown in default internet application ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I'm using the default internet application in ASP.NET MVC 3. When an error occurred in the application it automatically redirects to the default error page that is already available in the shared folder inside views.

I'm trying to figure out how does it happening? because i'm not seeing any settings in web.config or Global.asax that forces the application redirect to error page when an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in the `web.config`, it looks like:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

MVC has a default exception filter ([HandleError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) which provides built-in error handling for you.

Comment: i can't find it in the web.config. i wonder if it's the default setting? if it is how do they actually force the redirection.

Comment: The redirection is forced by the `HandleError` filter which is registered in the `Global.asax` file, if you want to change that behaviour you could introduce your own attribute which inherits from `HandleError` and register that before the default.

Comment: As far as i know (from looking at the source code), no redirection is involved.

Comment: @haim770 by redirection I believe the OP means the *view*, not an actual URL redirection (bad choice of word).

Answer (score 1):

It is usually caused by global `Action Filter` that is registered by default in your `global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Keep in mind though, that by default, the filter will NOT invoke itself if `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in your `Web.config`.

Please note that the `HandleError` filter **does not** use redirection, it simply replaces the original `ActionResult` of the requested `Action` with it's own `ViewResult` that uses the `Error.cshtml` view (unless otherwise specified).

See http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs